# What is the cause of BadWebPushTopic from https://web.push.apple.com?

Tags: apple-push-notifications, web-push

I receive sporadic from the Apple webpush API `https://web.push.apple.com/...` the response `{"reason":"BadWebPushTopic"}` with response code 400 . If I send the same message with the same `Topic` later it work without problems.

My `Topic` header has always 25 characters with 0-9 and a-z.

Any suggestion how to handle this error?

Answer (score 4):

After many tests, it seems that the topic size works with a factor of 4. Sounds like the Apple server try to decode it as base64. I have fill it with `0` to 32 characters, which is the max size for the topic.

Comment: I have noticed this more frequently with apple providers since September 2023. Some deployments happen to hit BadWebPushTopic with extremely high frequency, while others don't at all for the same topic text. @Horcrux7, did u have success with the above thesis?

Comment: I have never see again a BadWebPushTopic after I have extends it to 32 characters filled with "0".

Comment: Okay, thanks for confirming. It seems Apple requires Base64 with padding limited to 32 chars by length. meaning - the encoded result has to be max 32 bytes and encoded length in multiples of 4 otherwise padded with = in the end. Effectively reduces the topic to 24 chars if measured pre-Base64. Your answer lead me in the right direction. Thanks!